# How to compile php-cgi for arm-linux

Tags: php, gcc, compilation, arm, autoconf

Good morning,
i need to compile php 5.6.14 for arm-linux.

I have a Debian amd64 machine and I tried to compile with this methods:

```
'./configure' '--disable-all' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-sockets' '--disable-ipv6' '--with-curl=/home/******' '--enable-json' '--enable-session' '--host=arm-linux'

'./configure' '--disable-all' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-sockets' '--disable-ipv6' '--with-curl=/home/******' '--enable-json' '--enable-session' '--target=arm-linux'

'./configure' '--disable-all' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-sockets' '--disable-ipv6' '--with-curl=/home/******' '--enable-json' '--enable-session' '--build=arm-linux'

'./configure' '--disable-all' '--with-sqlite3' '--enable-cgi' '--enable-sockets' '--disable-ipv6' '--with-curl=/home/******' '--enable-json' '--enable-session' '--build=amd64' '--host=amd64' '--target=arm-linux'
```

also without quotes, and i gave the commands make && make test && make install but everytime i have this error with the php-cgi in /usr/local/bin/php-cgi, that i put in the other machine:

```
"500 Server Error: /var/web_server/cgi-bin/php-cgi /var/web_server/fastintellinet/fast.intellinet.tab.pc/phpinfo.php: Exec format error"
```

I see also that the size of file is not equal to the original file.

How can I fix?